# linking to an executable under OSX with CMake

Tags: macos, dll, cmake, linker, dynamic-linking

I have a plugin that will get loaded by an executable.

The executable exports symbols and here is some CMake for the executable:

```
set_target_properties(rcrl_compiler_tests PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS ON)
```

Then later I link to it like this:

```
target_link_libraries(test_plugin rcrl_compiler_tests)
```

This is fine for Windows and Linux. For macOS however it is not. I read I needed to use `-bundle_loader` as stated in the documentation for [`ENABLE_EXPORTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ENABLE_EXPORTS.html)

So I did the following:

```
target_compile_options(test_plugin PRIVATE -Wl,-bundle_loader,$<TARGET_FILE:rcrl_compiler_tests>)
```

But when I try to compile the plugin I get the following:

> clang: warning: -Wl,-bundle_loader,/Users/mario/rcrl/build/bin/rcrl_compiler_tests: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

The path to the executable from the generator expression is correct - but the flag itself isn't used.

And I still get linker errors for the only 2 symbols I need to export from the executable and use in the plugin.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `-bundle_loader` if you use `-undefined dynamic_lookup`.

Just use this for the link flags:

```
set_target_properties(TARGET PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-undefined dynamic_lookup \
    -Wl,-no_pie \
    -Wl,-search_paths_first"
)
```

...where `TARGET` is your dylib